# Label Propagation for weighted graph

Tags: apache-spark, graphs, social-network-analysis

I am working on "community detection" on a big network graph and I've been using the Label Propagation Algorithm from GraphFrames (Spark package).

However, my graph is weighted and I was wondering whether I can leverage some community detection algorithms which take into account weights.

My main limitation is that I should run the algorithm in parallel

Any ideas which algorithm should I look at?